# Host static website on Azure without $web in URL

Tags: azure, static, hosting

Following instructions in [Static website hosting in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) and [Add a custom domain to your endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal) I've managed to get a static website with a custom domain and https (albeit with a "www" subdomain) via Azure CDN.

However, the blob endpoint ends "/$web/index.html" and that is also required to access the custom domain. So it is of the form:

```
https://www.<customdomain>.com/$web/index.html
```

Because of the SPA framework I'm using, that immediately becomes:

```
https://www.<customdomain>.com/$web/index.html#/home
```

which is a bit long.

I see instructions for handling https on root custom domains and may give that try if I'm feeling brave. But is there a way to suppress the `/$web/index.html` part? Currently, if I go to:

```
https://www.<customdomain>.com
```

I get:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
  <Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid. RequestId:...</Message>
  <QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
  <QueryParameterValue/>
  <Reason/>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping your custom domain to regular blob endpoint (e.g. `https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`), please try to map it to static website endpoint which looks something like `https://mystorageaccount.z22.web.core.windows.net`.

Once you do that, then you will not need to specify `$web` in your requests as this endpoint always picks up the content from `$web` blob container.

You can find the static website endpoint for your storage account in going into `Static website` section for your storage account in Azure Portal.

Comment: Thanks. I must have misread the "Add a custom domain to your endpoint" article, specifically Step 1.4 where I used the instructions for "blob service" rather than "static website".

Comment: It may not be your fault at all. For reasons unknown, sometimes creating the CDN endpoint from the storage account defaults to using Storage Static Website and sometimes Storage. The latter results in this error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error when the CDN endpoint created from the storage account defaulted to a storage type of "Storage" instead of "Storage static website." While I don't have an explanation for why creating the CDN sometimes defaults to using a storage type of "Storage", changing Settings - Origin in the CDN endpoint config resolved this error for me.

[image: Azure Endpoint - Settings - Origin]